# Lipschitz constant of Fejer kernel is O(n)

Tags: fourier-series

Is it true that the Fejer kernel $\frac{\sin(nx/2)}{N\sin (x/2)}$ has Lipschitz constant $O(n)$, and if so, is there a straightforward proof that does not involve nasty calculus?